# ¿Se puede insertar un media query en un mixin de sass?

Tags: css, sass, mediaqueries

Hola me gustaria saber si se puede insertar un media query dentro de un mixin de sass? Afectaria en algo el código del css? o Genereraria un error?

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

**Editado**

El uso de content blocks tal y como menciona @blonfu puede llegar a ser muy útil, con la etiqueta `@content` podrás extender las capacidades de tu mixin.

En la documentación de [sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#content-blocks) podrás ver un excelente ejemplo que utiliza el content para aumentar la flexibilidad de tu mixin, para complementar el ejemplo que te ofrezco podemos añadir al mixin `boxBlue` la etiqueta content para utilizar un media query general que permita realizar operaciones extra.

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  margin: 30px;
}

@mixin boxBlue($mediaQuerySize) {
  @media (max-width: #{$mediaQuerySize}) {
    .box {
      background: blue;
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@include boxBlue(300px) { 
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Lo cual produce lo siguiente

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  margin: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .box {
    background: blue;
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pues es bastante util para definir *breakpoints* sobre todo usando *content blocks*

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda